# Set webpage for all screen resolution

Tags: html, css

I have created a webpage in asp.net. it works fine with normal screen. When displayed in wider screen there is lot of white spaces at the side and also at the bottom. How can i fit the page for all screen sizes. I saw in the earlier post to set the width in %. But it doesn't work out. Can anyone help me out in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Try posting a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) of the html/css issue you're facing.  This will help people understand where your problem lies and hopefully help you understand their answers.

Comment: I promise to write the entire html structure of your site if you can post something to work with in JSFiddle.

Okay, I'm kidding..but if that doesn't motivate you to explain your question properly, nothing will :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I agree you need to be more specific
try this css code.

```
body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Then you can create container DIVs with fixed percentage width and height
to create parts of you webpage such as header , sidebar, main content, footer...etc.

the % approach is the most viable approach if you use it correctly.
post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of the html/css/js to get specific help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the absolute positioning for root element (one step down from body tag) by defining top, right, bottom and left css properties. 
Something like this:
`#page{
    positioning: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}`
Then position other elements inside that root element.

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple of options:

Set the html or body tag to 100% width with a background. Then set the container for the rest of your site to a max-width of whatever pixel size you want. This will prevent your site from getting all stretched out and messy looking, but still solve the blank space problem. Something like this:

```
body {
background:#HEX url(images/2000pxwideimage.png);
width:100%;
}

#wrapper {
max-width:960px;
}
```

You can use css3 media queries to adjust the layout of your site according to screen width.
The advantage of this is that you can accommodate for smaller and larger screen sizes
while keeping your layout aesthetically pleasing which in some cases may mean providing significantly different css. An example might be a horizontal navigation, that at a smaller screen size you want to be a vertical navigation for ease of use. That would look something like this:

```
@media (min-width:960px) {
/* Browser window must be at least 960px wide to get these rules */
}

@media (max-width:320px) {
/* Something similar to this would work for very small screens like phones */
}
```